Difference in location of the exhaust nozzle between F-35 and Saab Gripen
The F-35 exhaust nozzle is located a little inside the empennage but in Saab Gripen it is located a little extended from the empennage
What is the reason?
Will this different location of the exhaust nozzle influence the rate of turn?

What you are referring to is not actually the afterburner, it is the jet exhaust nozzle. The afterburner is a system inside the exhaust duct of the engine.


The F-35 exhaust nozzle is located a little inside the empennage but in Saab Gripen it is located a little extended from the empennage. What is the reason?

It's because you are comparing two very different kinds of empennage.

Regarding the vertical stabiliser: The F-35 (in its C version) is a carrier-capable aircraft. This implies that its maximum height is limited by the height of the decks/elevators of the aircraft-carrier more than by aerodynamic considerations. This is why this kind of aircraft normally have two small vertical stabilisers instead of a single big one like the Gripen. Stealth reasons can as well dictate the use of the same canted twin-tail configuration, like seen for example on the F-22:

Already this single reason explains the different location of the vertical tailplanes in respect to the engine exhaust: with a single stabiliser you want it to be mounted as rear as possible on the fuselage in order to maximise its leverarm (and minimise its size and weight); when you have two of them, they can be somewhat more freely positioned also according to other reasons, like the already mentioned stealth requirements.

Regarding the horizontal stabiliser: Well, here the difference is even bigger and it is obviously due to the fact that the F-35 has a conventional tailplane while the Gripen has a canard configuration:

Here you cannot have the exhaust "located a little inside the empennage" simply because there's no empennage.
Also other canard fighters like the Dassault Rafale in the following picture or the Eurofighter have a similar exhaust configuration like the Saab:

If the Gripen had had a conventional tailplane then it would have also been... well, on the tail! and the exhaust would have been consequently "located a little inside the empennage", just like on a F-16 for example:


All pictures from Wikipedia

I will contest the claim of carrier hangar deck height being a design factor for F-35 height. S-3 viking had a folding tail, and many carrier acft are/were taller than 5 meters, limiting height being somewhere around 5.3m. Other factors such as aerodynamics and stealth capabilities are of importance here.

I wrote "normally" not "exclusively"  Sure, they are canted mainly for stealth reasons. F-35 is indeed 4.5m high, a single vertical stabiliser would have been definitely higher than the limitations you've given. I'll update my answer with your comment, thanks.

Counter example within same manufacturer, Viggen!

@user721108: the Viggen is (was) a lifting-canard design i.e. the canard is used not only to control the airplane but also to provide lift. That implies that the main wing has to be located as backward as possible in order to give anyway a good longitudinal CG excursion and stability.


All aircraft need to have some of the vertical tail offset forward or backwards from any horizontal surface. This allows yaw control at high angle of attack, by keeping air flowing past the tails. Fighter aircraft would prefer to have a lot of the vertical tail unblanketed at high AOA, because near and post stall manuverability is key to their performance. The F-35 achieves this by having the horizontal control surfaces stick out way behind the engine exhaust and vertical tails, the Gripen achieves this by having the engine exhaust and vertical tail stick way behind the delta wing
Image from https://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/HOOU/AircraftDesign_9_EmpennageGeneralDesign.pdf
